# Active SQL Connections with Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a standard Joomla Installation for my website.

Under the Administrator panel, i have set up session handler as "database" and session time as "60 minutes".

Will Joomla keep SQL connection active till 60 minutes or just the user session?

If i write a custom PHP script outside of Joomla, do i need to manually open and close database connection or can i use Joomla's connection?

Also, does Joomla takes care of automatically closing active database connections?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla! Opens and closes when necessary. So pretty much every page load a connection is opened if not already open.

Your session means that you are logged in, and that's it. It doesn't keep the connection open.